# シェルスクリプトからのコマンド実行でエラー: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません

Tags: bash, shellscript

PostgreSQLをbashで起動させようとしています。

下記のシェルスクリプトをLinuxで実行したのですが、以下のように怒られてしまいます。

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

"/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D /data/pgsql"

echo -e "完了"
exit 0
```

**実行時のエラー**

```
./test.sh: 行 3: /usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D /data/pgsql: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません
```

試しにLinuxで直接下記を実行すると、DBが起動できました。

```
/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D /data/pgsql"
```

シェルスクリプトの書き方がおかしいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

この場合クォートは余計な気がします。クォート無しだとどうでしょうか。

```
/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D /data/pgsql
```

Comment: cubick♦さま　ありがとうございます。ご指定のやり方でDB起動ができました。（上記シェルスクリプトを実行した後psql db名でログインできることまで確認できました！）